# How to append a char to a std::string?

Tags: c++, string

The following fails with the error `prog.cpp:5:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’`

```
int main()
{
  char d = 'd';
  std::string y("Hello worl");
  y.append(d); // Line 5 - this fails
  std::cout << y;
  return 0;
}
```

I also tried, the following, which compiles but behaves randomly at runtime:

```
int main()
{
  char d[1] = { 'd' };
  std::string y("Hello worl");
  y.append(d);
  std::cout << y;
  return 0;
}
```

Sorry for this dumb question, but I've searched around google, what I could see are just "char array to char ptr", "char ptr to char array", etc.

Comment: a compiler error yes..I forgot what the error is, but it's reasonable.

Comment: You have better answers below, but you can make you second example working like this char d[2] = {'d', 0}; or just char d[2] = "d"; Basically, you need a 0 to terminate your c-style string you pass to append

Answer (score 306, accepted):

```
y += d;
```

I would use `+=` operator instead of named functions.

Comment: why do you consider += better than push_back?  Is it just less typing or do you have another reason?

Comment: It's less typing.  In `gcc`, `basic_string::operator+=` is just a call in `push_back`.

Comment: It is more natural IMO for strings. push_back is container function, and a string is a specialized one in STL :)

Comment: Let's turn that question around: Why do you consider push_back better than +=? In my opinion, += is clear and concise.

Comment: You want to be careful with this because if you get into the habit, this will compile just fine if `y` is a `char*` instead of `std::string`. It'd add `d` characters to the pointer y.

Answer (score 100):

Use `push_back()`:

```
std::string y("Hello worl");
y.push_back('d')
std::cout << y;
```

Answer (score 24):

To add a char to a std::string var using the append method, you need to use this overload:

```
std::string::append(size_type _Count, char _Ch)
```

**Edit :
Your're right I misunderstood the size_type parameter, displayed in the context help. This is the number of chars to add. So the correct call is**

```
s.append(1, d);
```

not

```
s.append(sizeof(char), d);
```

Or the simpliest way :

```
s += d;
```

Comment: I think using sizeof is not semantically correct here (even though it happens to work as sizeof(char) is always one). The append method is naturally more useful if you want to append more copies of the same character!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Why are you using `sizeof(char)` instead of `1`? You want to append exactly one repetition of `d`, so just say that. Using `sizeof` here is misleading since it suggests that one has to tell `append` the byte size of the data type used (which is not the case).

Comment: As Unclebens said, the append method is really more useful when adding the same character many times.

Comment: append() is not useful to append a single char which is what the op asked for.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the others mentioned, one of the string constructors take a char and the number of repetitions for that char. 
So you can use that to append a single char.

```
std::string s = "hell";
s += std::string(1, 'o');
```

Comment: This is neither faster nor better in any other way than `+=` or `push_back()`.

Answer (score 12):

I test the several propositions by running them into a large loop.
I used microsoft visual studio 2015 as compiler and my processor is an i7, 8Hz, 2GHz.

```
    long start = clock();
    int a = 0;
    //100000000
    std::string ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < 60000000; i++)
    {
        ret.append(1, ' ');
        //ret += ' ';
        //ret.push_back(' ');
        //ret.insert(ret.end(), 1, ' ');
        //ret.resize(ret.size() + 1, ' ');
    }
    long stop = clock();
    long test = stop - start;
    return 0;
```

According to this test, results are :

```
     operation             time(ms)            note
------------------------------------------------------------------------
append                     66015
+=                         67328      1.02 time slower than 'append'
resize                     83867      1.27 time slower than 'append'
push_back & insert         90000      more than 1.36 time slower than 'append'
```

**Conclusion**

`+=` seems more understandable, but if you mind about speed, use append

Comment: For such an answer to be meaningful, you should a least tell what compiler are you using, because such things might vary a LOT.
Telling about your processor can be great too, to get a rough estimate on the actual impact this might have.

Comment: I used visual studio 2015. I will look for gcc to do some other tests.My processor is i7, 8 hearts, 2.20 Ghz....But whatever is my processor it will have no impact on std::string implementation...except if some of these method are multithreaded and someothers not.

Comment: Sometimes it has an impact, especially if you are showing timings in milliseconds. Instead you could show in percentage relative to fastest method(So actual processor speed is irrelevant) Also move that data from the comment to your answer, this is just general StackExchange etiquette. Otherwise nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try the += operator [link text](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/),
append() method [link text](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/),
or push_back() method [link text](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/)

The links in this post also contain examples of how to use the respective APIs.

Answer (score 3):

the problem with:

```
std::string y("Hello worl");
y.push_back('d')
std::cout << y;
```

is that you have to have the 'd' as opposed to using a name of a char, like char d = 'd'; Or am I wrong?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine. I have `char c = 'd'` and I can do `y.push_back(c)` without issue. So there is no problem with `std::string::push_back()` (except that it's longer than `+=`).

Answer (score 3):

Also adding insert option, as not mentioned yet.

```
std::string str("Hello World");
char ch;

str.push_back(ch);  //ch is the character to be added
OR
str.append(sizeof(ch),ch);
OR
str.insert(str.length(),sizeof(ch),ch) //not mentioned above
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
  char d = 'd';
  std::string y("Hello worl");

  y += d;
  y.push_back(d);
  y.append(1, d); //appending the character 1 time
  y.insert(y.end(), 1, d); //appending the character 1 time
  y.resize(y.size()+1, d); //appending the character 1 time
  y += std::string(1, d); //appending the character 1 time
}
```

Note that in all of these examples you could have used a character literal directly: `y += 'd';`.

Your second example *almost* would have worked, for unrelated reasons. `char d[1] = { 'd'};` didn't work, but `char d[2] = { 'd'};` (note the array is size two) would have been worked roughly the same as `const char* d = "d";`, and a string literal *can* be appended: `y.append(d);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the d as pointer
y.append(*d)

Comment: That's dangerous as a single `char` is no string and has no null-terminator. Doing this causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is just wrong. `*d` means de-reference pointer `d` which is a syntax error since `d` isn't a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way...
I needed to tack a `char` on to a string that was being built on the fly.  I needed a `char list;` because I was giving the user a choice and using that choice in a `switch()` statement.

I simply added another `std::string Slist;` and set the new string equal to the character, "list" - a, b, c or whatever the end user chooses like this:

```
char list;
std::string cmd, state[], Slist;
Slist = list; //set this string to the chosen char;
cmd = Slist + state[x] + "whatever";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Complexity may be cool but simplicity is cooler. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

> there are three ways to do this:
> for example, we have code like this:
> `std::string str_value = "origin";`
> `char c_append = 'c';`
>
> 1. we usually use push_back().
>    `str_value.push_back(c)`
> 2. use += .
>    `str_value += c`
> 3. use append method.
>    `str_value.append(1,c)`
>    And you can learn more about the methods of string from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Does not seem to be much better than @MooingDuck 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Supplementary answer, because apparently [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472067/20158640) with many upvotes is suggesting to use `push_back('c')` while [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38081424/20158640) is suggesting not to. Since both answers were a bit old, let's have an update.

Using the STL, libstdc++ by the GNU, the performance of the following 5 methods of appending a `char` to a `std::string` will be tested: `str.append()`, `str += 'c'`, `str.resize(str.size() + 1, 'c')`, `str.push_back('c')`, and `str.insert(str.end(), 1, 'c')`.

Let *t* be the minimum time used amongst the operations, the results are as follows:

| params \ cpu_time (4dp) | `append()` | `+=` | `resize()` | `push_back()` | `insert()` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [optim = none compiler = Clang 11.0 std = c++11](https://quick-bench.com/q/QBJ0yTFQLEl9kHjtmBwAdA5wDwg) | 2.6255 1.1*t* | 2.4826 *t* | 3.3396 1.3*t* | 2.4759 *t* | 4.5967 2*t* |
| [optim = none compiler = Clang 15.0 std = c++20](https://quick-bench.com/q/aLtKVEM02WIAE9O8aXDeIAu2iyU) | 14.1841 1.5*t* | 9.3077 *t* | 15.7846 1.7*t* | 9.7907 1.1*t* | 27.1050 2*t* |
| [optim = O3 compiler = Clang 11.0 std = c++11](https://quick-bench.com/q/QIDh7NJTuB_5TujgwrAno0tvV3Q) | 19.1018 2*t* | 9.9812 *t* | 25.1597 2.5*t* | 10.0466 *t* | 17.5578 2*t* |
| [optim = O3 compiler = Clang 15.0 std = c++20](https://quick-bench.com/q/sf-0m5pYBws7TuwOgB9arYQuUz4) | 9.9465 *t* | 9.8468 *t* | 9.9519 *t* | 9.8686 *t* | 9.9145 *t* |

The `+=` operator and `push_back()` are consistently the quickest method, followed by `append()` (1.1*t* - 2*t*), `resize()` (1.3*t* - 2.5*t*), and `insert()` (2*t*)

Answer (score 0):

```
str.append(10u,'d'); //appends character d 10 times
```

Notice I have written **10u** and not 10 for the number of times I'd like to append the character; replace 10 with whatever number.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the push_back there is no call for the string constructor. Otherwise it will create a string object via casting, then it will add the character in this string to the other string. Too much trouble for a tiny character ;)

Comment: operator +=(char c); is overloaded for strings. In fact, the string constructor doesn't accept one character, see Brian answer ;)