# How do this except string.resize?

Tags: c++, string, resize

How to write this code without the resize function? **wartosc.resize(10);**

Because without use resize in string, nothing happens - doesn't assign values.

```
string naBinarny(int liczba){

    string wartosc;
    int i=0;

    wartosc.resize(10);

    while (liczba>0) {
        wartosc[i] = ((liczba%2) == 1 ? '1' : '0');

        liczba=liczba/2;

        i++;

    }


    return wartosc;
}
```

Comment: You should add a tag for the language you are working in.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472048/how-to-append-a-char-to-a-stdstring

Comment: How about `string wartosc(10, 0);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
string naBinarny(int liczba){

string wartosc="";
int i=0;

    while (liczba>0) {
        wartosc += ((liczba%2) == 1 ? "1" : "0");

        liczba=liczba/2;

        i++;

   }


    return wartosc;
}
```