# Why is std::string::append() less powerful than std::string::operator+()?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I noticed that

```
std::string str;
str += 'b'; // works
str.append('b'); // does not work
str.append(1, 'b'); // works, but not as nice as the previous
```

Is there any reason why the `append` method does not support a single character to be appended? I assumed that the `operator+=` is actually a wrapper for the `append` method, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It's technically not that it's less powerful, but that nobody thought that it was necessary to write a `std::string::append(char)`. Use `+=` if you want to do that...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472048/how-to-append-a-char-to-a-stdstring

Comment: You can use `std::string::append(count, char)` with `count=1`or `std::string::push_back(char)`

Comment: The facetious answer is that nobody has ever managed to convince the C++ standards committee of its necessity. Could you? Nice question though. I can't see that introducing the necessary overload would break anything.

Comment: @Niall: The committee is probably smarter than you are giving them credit for. I cannot speak for them, but I see it like this: To the compiler, `char` is just another integer type. On certain platforms, `sizeof( char )` and `sizeof( int )` might actually be identical. Look at the list of `std::string` constructors, and `append()` overloads. Having an overload that takes a single integer value might be somewhat error-prone -- and you *do* have the sematically identical `std::string( "b" )`, `append( "b" )`, `operator+=( "b" )`, and `operator+=( 'b' )`. `+=` has only the one integer overload.

Comment: `std::string` has a `push_back()` method that takes a single char parameter, `operator+=` just calls `append` or `push_back` depending on its parameter type.

Comment: @DevSolar. It was not a critique on their intelligence. The class is large and that use case may not have been considered for the method `append`.

Comment: The std::string class is poorly designed. The interface is inconsistent with itself, with other containers and not feature-rich enough even for basic tasks. I constantly need to look into the reference to find out what is supported and what not, and I constantly need to write even the most basic utility functions in every project, again and again. I vote for adding the overload, and the rest of the 20-30 missing string functions. We do not even have "contains". No, wait, we will have it, with C++23!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interesting to note that the form of `append` here;

```
string& append( size_type count, CharT ch );
```

Mirrors the constructor taking [similar input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

```
basic_string( size_type count, 
              CharT ch, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

And some other methods that take a `count` with a character, such as `resize( size_type count, CharT ch );`.

The string class is large and it is possible that the particular use case (and overload) for `str.append('b');` was not considered, or the alternatives were considered sufficient.

Just simple the introduction of a single overload for this could introduce ambiguity if the integrals `int` and `char` correspond (on some platforms this may be the case).

There are several alternatives to the `append` adding a single character.

- Adding a string containing a single character can be done `str.append("b");`. Albeit that this not exactly the same, it has the same effect.
- As mentioned there is `operator+=`
- There is also `push_back()`, which is consistent with other standard containers

Point is, it was probably never considered as a use case (or strong enough use case), thus, a suitable overload/signature was not added to `append` to cater for it.

---

Alternative designs could be debated, but given the maturity of the standard and this class, it is unlikely they will be changed soon - it could very well break a lot of code.

Alternate signatures for `append` could also be considered; one possible solution could have been to reverse the order of the `count` and `char` (possibly adding a default);

```
string& append(CharT ch, size_type count = 1);
```

Another, as described in some of the [critique of `basic_string`](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) is to remove `append`, there are many methods to achieve what it does.

Answer (score 6):

I figure that `operator+=()` is intended to handle all the simple cases (taking only one parameter), while `append()` is for things that require more than one parameter.

I am actually more surprised about the *existence* of the single-parameter `append( const basic_string& str )` and `append( const CharT* s )` than about the *absence* of `append( CharT c )`.

Also note my comment above: `char` is just an integer type. Adding a single-parameter, integer-type overload to `append()` -- or the constructor (which, by design, have *several* integer-type overloads already) might introduce ambiguity.

Unless somebody finds some written rationale, or some committee members post here what they remember about the discussion, that's probably as good an explanation as any.