# Garbage when converting character to string using concatenation

Tags: c++, c++11

I am converting a character to a string by concatenating it with an empty string (""). But it results in undefined behaviour or garbage characters in the resultant string. Why so?

```cpp
char c = 'a';
string s = ""+c;
cout<<s<<" "<<s.size()<<"\n";
```

Comment: `""` is not a `string`

Comment: Try `string s = ""s + c`;  (unless you're truly limited to C++11).  Then read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

Comment: @MooingDuck Could you explain why "" is not a string? I thought ("") is a constant string literal, just like integers 1,2,3 etc. are constant literals.

Comment: It is a string literal, but the type of `""` is `const char[1]`, not `std::string`. The naming is a bit confusing, I admit.

Comment: Use +=, '+' does not work as such operator is not defined for `char`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472048/how-to-append-a-char-to-a-stdstring

Comment: Clang will also give you warning: `warning: adding 'char' to a string does not append to the string` https://godbolt.org/z/Pcj85vEe5

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I again run the code with `char c = '\0';` and it ran with size of 's' to be 0. Could you explain what's happening exactly ?

Comment: @AryanAgarwal `string s = ""+c;` -- Did you get this idea from reading Java code or code from another computer language?  This looks a lot like how this would be done in another language.

Comment: There is the exact duplicate about a garbage in the result of `"str" + c` in C or C++, but it is difficult to find.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think I coded something like that in python or javascript

Comment: @AryanAgarwal Well, this is why you should never use other languages as a model in writing C++ code.  Not only that, this looks totally weird to a C++ programmer (that line of code).  That was the red flag -- this looks totally fine to a JavaScript programmer, but is totally alien to a C++ programmer who never used those other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your snippet, one statement or a line at a time.

```
char c = 'a';
```

This is valid, assigning a character literal to a variable of type `char`.
*Note: since `c` is not changed after this statement, you may want to declare the definition as const.*

```
string s = ""+c;
```

Let's refactor:
`std::string s = ("" + c);`

Let's add type casting to make the point more clear:
`std::string s = ((const char *) "" + (char) c);`

The order of operations is resolve all expressions on the *right hand side* (rhs) of the assignment operator before assigning to the string variable.

There is no `operator+()` in C++ that takes a `const char *` and a single character.
The compiler is looking for this function:  `operator+(const char *, char)`.
This is the primary reason for the compilation errors.

`cout<<s<<" "<<s.size()<<"\n";`
The string assignment and creation failed, thus `s` is empty and `s.size()` is zero.

Comment: *There is no operator+() in C++ that takes a const char * and a single character.* but there is one that takes a pointer and integer. There are no compiler errors here, just UB.

Comment: So, the compiler tries to find the "best match" for the operator, but realizes that `(char) c` can be converted to an `int` and applies the `operator+(char *, int)`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- there's no "best match" involved; "best match" is the algorithm for choosing one of several viable overloads of a function. That's not what's going on here; it's straight C, with a pointer and an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting issue, which looks like an issue which the compiler does not detect at compilation.
I have tried this with GNU C++ 10.2 on Cygwin and your code snippet generates this.

```
0200312 (Fedora Cygwin 9.3.0-1) 31
```

if you replace `char c = 'c';` with `char c = '\0';` the output is

```
 0
```

So looks like some kind of memory violation issue.

As you probably know, the standard method of appending a char is to use `push_back`

```cpp
string s = "";
s.push_back(c);
cout << s << " " << s.size() << "\n";
```

Alternatively you can use the operator `+=`

```cpp
string s = "";
s += c;
cout << s << " " << s.size() << "\n";
```